# Find all integers in string C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need to find the sum of all the integers in a string:

> bl1a:bl3a: blaspecial:1\r\nblab7la\r\n\r\nbla:bla: blaspecial:4\r\nbl9abla\r\n\r\nb4la:bla: blaspecial:2\r\nblabla\r\n\r\n

The main rules for the `int` in the `string` is that it starts with `":"`, ends with `"\r\n"`, and could be `from 1 to 5`.

I tried to play with `SubString` but with no results:

```
var reg=new Regex("blaspecial", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var mathes=reg.Matches(tempStr);
var l=mathes.Count;
var a=0;

for(var i=0; i<l; i++) 
{
    tempStr=tempStr.Substring(
        tempStr.IndexOf("blaspecial:", StringComparison.Ordinal)+11);

    var r=tempStr.Substring(0, 1);
    a=a+int.Parse(r);
}
```

Comment: If you have 'played around with substring' surely you most have some code that you can share too?

Comment: I'd play around with `IndexOf`, in particular the overload that takes a start index.

Comment: Concerning regex, `@":(\d)\r\n"` might do what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this to add all the integers in your string together:

```
var sum = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+")
               .Cast<Match>()
               .Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value))
               .Sum();
```

Or this to limit the result to only integers in the pattern `:123\r\n`

```
var sum = Regex.Matches(input, @":(\d+)\r\n")
               .Cast<Match>()
               .Select(m => int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value))
               .Sum();
```

When called with your input string, both will output `7`.

Comment: Just to be safe, the regex should include the `:` and `\r\n`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that ints can be everywhere in string but I need only those which starts with : and ends with \r\n

Comment: @Ars I've added that solution to my answer as well.

Comment: @ p.s.w.g You are cool!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something a regular expression is good for.

```
^.*:(?<digit>\d)\s*$
```

- `^` matches the start of a line.
- `.*` matches any character, zero or more times.
- `:` matches the literal character '`:`'.
- `(?<digit> )` puts the matched contents in the `digit` group.
- `\d` matches a single digit. (`\d+` would match one or more digits.)
- `\s*` matches some whitespace if it exists.
- `$` matches the end of the line.

Then you use the [`Regex` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)  with the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option. For example:

```
string input = "bla:bla: blaspecial:1\r\n...";

int sum = 0;
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"^.*:(?<digit>\d)\s*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var group = match.Groups["digit"];
    if (group.Success)
    {
        int value = Int32.Parse(group.Value);
        sum += value;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

This will only get those integers that are directly preceded by `:` and succeeded by whitespace and a line separator.